# How to find SQL credentials from a .Net binary?

Tags: sql, passwords

I have an .Net application named "abcd.EXE" with a "abcd.exe.config" file beside it.

Content of config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SqlPath" value="data source=192.168.1.1\companyname;connection timeout=120;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;workstation id=SOMETHING;packet size=4096;initial catalog=" />
    </appSettings>
< /configuration>
```

I can decompile EXE file with reflector.

How should I find the connection password?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> `integrated security=SSPI`

Luckly the program authors used a proper authentication strategy and did not embed passwords in the program or config file. Integrated authentication means the program will connect using the credentials of the principal running the process.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string uses the **integrated security=SSPI**

the value can be `true/false/yes/no` or `SSPI` (the Security Support Provider Interface).
When SSPI is used it is equal to **true**!

**false**: User ID and Password are specified in the connection.

**true**: the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

more info: **[SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**